# GVim Specify Directory for :browse open Command

Tags: vim, gvim, ubuntu-11.04, vimrc

I have added the line:

```
:browse open
```

to my `vimrc` file, but have been unsuccessful in getting GVim to open a file browser starting in a specified directory. In particular, I would like to know if it is possible to have GVim open up the file browser in my home directory on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:cd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Acd) to have Vim always change to your home directory (e.g. before your `:browse` command).

For example, in your `.vimrc` (or even better, in your `.gvimrc` (since [`:browse`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Abrowse) only works in GUI mode)):

```
⋮
cd           " defaults to HOME
browse open
```